# Iterate over a value in a handlebars template

Tags: handlebars.js

In my JSON object I have an property say **i** which specifies a loop value.
What I would like to is to iterate it in my HTML template and output that many instances of a character, say "-".
Im trying to achieve something like this :

```
<td>
for i = 1 to {{i}}: print "-"
{{name}}
</td>
```

Is this even possible ?
So if the JSON object has like {i:5, name:"John"}
it should output -----John

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Handlebars doesn't provide anything like this out of the box. However, you can define your own helper for this task:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('character', function(character, times) {
  var out = "";

  for(var i=0, times; i<times; ++i) {
    out += character;
  }

  return out;
});
```

Sample usage:

```
{{character "-" 5}}{{name}}
```